# Pretty URL .htaccess gives 404 not found

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm really not that good at writing htaccess. It looks like gibberish for me. :-)

So what we wan't to do, is to remove the .php extension to the URL.

Here we have our script

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

RewriteRule    ^help/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$    help.php?artid=$1    [NC,L]    # Process parrots
RewriteRule    ^signature/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$    signature.php?artid=$1    [NC,L]    # Process parrots
RewriteRule    ^signatures/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$    signatures.php?artid=$1    [NC,L]    # Process parrots

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

I really cant find the issue here.
The issue is, that when i f.x goto localhost/secure/profil it gives me a 404 not found. But when i comment ALL the .htaccess out, and goto localhost/secure/profil.php it works.

The exact url when htaccess is turned on looks like this:

```
http://localhost/secure/profil/
```

Maybe somebody can see what i'm doing wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated!

Kind Regards!

Comment: Try and disable `MultiViews`, it is often the culprit in such situations when you have URLs that “partially” match existing files or folders.

Comment: @Cbroe  - doesn't work :( Thanks for your comment :D

Comment: What happens if you remove the trailing slash part? I also suck at .htaccess but I've always found issues when working with a trailing slash

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Hmm, that doesnt work :(